# find needed details of my own private obfs4 Tor bridge

Tags: bridge, ubuntu, obfs4, private

I've set up a private obfs4 Tor bridge following the official tutorial, `PublishServerDescriptor` set to `0`. `/var/log/tor/log` shows positive entries so it should be configured correctly. The machine is Ubuntu x64.

I can find my fingerprint, hashed one, ip:port but I miss some data to be able to use this bridge with tor browser as it asks for 2 more entries.

Where can I find the "cert" and "iat-mode" entries that any obfs4 bridge on https://bridges.torproject.org has??

I cant find it in the logs and since its a private bridge it wont show up on the lists.

Answer (score 5):

From the obfs4proxy [README](https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/obfs4.git/tree/README.md):

> - The autogenerated obfs4 bridge parameters are placed in
>     `DataDir/pt_state/obfs4_state.json`.  To ease deployment, the client side
>     bridge line is written to `DataDir/pt_state/obfs4_bridgeline.txt`.

So `/var/lib/tor/pt_state/obfs4_bridgeline.txt`.